# How to deal with apache import error when deploying flask?

Tags: apache, python-2.7, flask, wsgi

I'm trying to deploy flask to my aws EC2 instance running Amazon Linux to no avail.I have flask install both globally and in a virtual environment. I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. When trying to visit my site, I get an Internal Server Error stating that: The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request. When digging through the logs i see the following:

```
[Thu May 28 02:25:27 2015] [error] [client 45.160.040.111]     from flask import Flask, render_template,redirect,request,url_for, flash, session
[Thu May 28 02:25:27 2015] [error] [client 45.160.040.111] ImportError: No    module named flask
[Thu May 28 02:25:28 2015] [error] [client 45.160.040.111] mod_wsgi (pid=1565): Target WSGI script '/var/www/Foodie-Web-Application/foodie/app.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module.
[Thu May 28 02:25:28 2015] [error] [client 45.160.040.111] mod_wsgi (pid=1565): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/Foodie-Web-Application/foodie/app.wsgi'.
[Thu May 28 02:25:28 2015] [error] [client 45.160.040.111] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu May 28 02:25:28 2015] [error] [client 45.160.040.111]   File "/var/www/Foodie-Web-Application/foodie/app.wsgi", line 9, in <module>
[Thu May 28 02:25:28 2015] [error] [client 45.160.040.111]     from routes import app  as application
[Thu May 28 02:25:28 2015] [error] [client 45.160.040.111]   File "/var/www/Foodie-Web-Application/foodie/app/routes.py", line 1, in <module>
[Thu May 28 02:25:28 2015] [error] [client 45.160.040.111]     from flask import Flask, render_template,redirect,request,url_for, flash, session
[Thu May 28 02:25:28 2015] [error] [client 45.160.040.111] ImportError: No module named flask
```

Here is my wsgi file :

```
activate_this = '/var/www/Foodie-Web-Application/foodie_venv/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/var/www/Foodie-Web-Application/foodie/app')
from routes import app  as application
```

My config file :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName ec2-56-24-1990-35662.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
          WSGIDaemonProcess app
     WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Foodie-Web-Application/foodie/app.wsgi

     <Directory /var/www/Foodie-Web-Application/foodie/app>
            WSGIProcessGroup app
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
     </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here is the file structure:

```
/var/www/Foodie-Web-Application:
   /foodie_venv #virtual environment: flask is also installed here
   /foodie 
     /app #The Flask App
        app.py
        search_results.py
        yes.py
       /static
       /templates
```

Comment: Amazon may have mod_wsgi compiled for an older Python version. Can't remember what they supply. Add 'import sys; print(sys.version)' at the start of your WSGI file and see what it says.

Comment: Looks like it prints Python 2.7.9

Comment: Print out the value of sys.path just before the import for your routes module, wherever that is supposed to be coming from. Check that that it includes where Flask is installed.